# Find extremal values of a given quotient

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

There is a given naturaln $n$ and positive variables : $$x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}$$

> Find maximal (and minimal) value of o given quotient:
>   $$f(x_{1},...,x_{n}):=\frac{\sum_{i}(x_{i}-A)^3}{(\sum_{i}(x_{i}-A)^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

Where $1\le i\le n$.

$$A=\frac{\sum_{i}x_{i}}{n}$$

I made some calculation and i suspect that $|f|\le 2$, however i can't prove it.

This question is connected to probability theory. It means $$f(X)=\frac{\mu_{3}(X)}{(\mu_{2}(X))^{\frac{1}{2}}}$$. Where $X$ is some random variable.

Comment: Did you run numerical experiment? The supremum seems to be $\frac{n-2}{\sqrt{n(n-1)}}$.